# unable to upload a self-signed certificate to our azure app registration

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, azure-ad

I have this script to generate a self-signed certificate:-

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName "SPGPIntegration-Test"                                                                               



PS C:\Users\Administrator> Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\LocalMachine\my\99CE213D84E71DFFE4D34E970162C6D4D6201D25 -FilePath "C:\certificates\SPGPIntegration-Test.pfx" -Password $pwd


                                                                                                                                 



PS C:\Users\Administrator> Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\LocalMachine\my\99CE213D84E71DFFE4D34E970162C6D4D6201D25 -FilePath 

"C:\certificates\SPGPIntegration-Test.crt" -Password $pwd
```

Then i tried to upload the generated .crt file inside the >> inside our azure app registration >> but got this error:-

[image]

so the error is saying to upload the crt file and i am doing so... any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export-PfxCertificate` will export the certificate as a PFX file. It's a non sense to indicate `.cer` extension with this command. Use [Export-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) instead.

Try this command:

```
$certName = "SPGPIntegration-Test"
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=$certName" }
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -Type CERT -FilePath "$certName.cer"
```

And insert the `.cer` file in your App Registration > Certificates & secrets.

[image: upload a certificate]

Comment: yes you are correct. thanks